# How can I extract EXIF information from an image and display it?

Tags: graphics, jpeg

I would like to build a function that inserts a JPG in a xelatex file and automatically caption it with information extracted from the JPG's EXIF data, such as exposure time, etc. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know anything about xelatex, but this question shows how to extract the EXIF data to a text file using imagemagick at the command line.  Maybe that could be part of your automated workflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654709/extract-exif-data-as-text-using-imagemagick

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to extract exif info through the command line and I'm familiar with some of them. I'm hoping for a more straightforward way, possibly with some package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`bashful`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bashful) to run external commands, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=90mm]{image.jpg}
\bash[stdout]
exiftool image.jpg
\END
\end{document}
```

[image]