# Why did LaTeX rotate my picture?

Tags: graphics

I inserted a picture in LaTeX, but it rotated my picture. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{1.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

All the files are here:[files](https://bthc-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/mr_iem_im/EhlWAFwa2ChDl6HAkDbcvwkBE4zHi-igvvwEcJwzmXKq3w?e=oReaiN)

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244871/jpg-image-is-flipped-upside-down

Answer (score 18):

The meta data of your image contains the tag "orientation" with the value "rotate 90 CW". This value is obeyed by most image viewers, but, as it seems, not LaTeX. Your best approach is probably to rotate that image yourself, as you have found out.

Comment: Interesting. So the keyword of relevance seems to be Exif. Do you know, if there’s a tool, which can correct the orientation, e.g. as a batch run?

Comment: Ah, I see it might be the program exiftool https://exiftool.org/ , which could be called by Latex via package bashful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296767/how-can-i-extract-exif-information-from-an-image-and-display-it

Comment: @MS-SPO if you're looking for a tool to batch rotate a lot of images based on exif data, ImageMagick is a very versatile and powerful option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456036/detect-exif-orientation-and-rotate-image-using-imagemagick

Answer (score 7):

It seems to depend on the jpg-File. When I save your foto as png without applying any rotation to it using Paint.net, it seems to be as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.05]{1.jpg}
    \caption{The jpg-image}
  \end{figure}
  
  % --- saving the jpg as png with Paint.net
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.05]{1b}
    \caption{The png-image}
  \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image: jpg and png on one page]

**P.S.:** According to comments and answer I tried this site http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi, which provides the Exif-tool online, to read out metadata contained in your photo 1.jpg, see screenshot.

As you can see, it's a pretty long list, which dependes on the photo, AND it sets the flag to "Rotate 90 CW". In contrast this flag is missing in the png I created.

BTW: I now know your smartphone model, when and where you took the photo etc. ... you just shared it.

[image: Excerpt of Exif-data of metadata in 1.jpg]

Comment: But when I opened the jpg-file, it is as your figure 2. Why in Latex, it becomes figure 1 in your answer?

Comment: I confirm your observation and have no idea why this is, should or could be ... Anyway I showed you a workaround :) // If you watch the Linked and Related columns to the right, or search here, you'll see, you're not alone. And you'll find even more workarounds there. // Probably it's relevant what's inside the jpg on binary level, not what programs make of it, like explorer or photo viewers ...

Comment: I try to solve this problem by rotate it: `\includegraphics[angle=270,width=\textwidth]`. But it is a little trouble.